# iOS launch image won't show up on iPhone or simulator, works on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, launchimage

I'm having this problem whether I use asset catalogs or the old-school way. Xcode 5.1.1 in all cases.

I've got all my images in, and Xcode does not give me the "you're missing the 568-h" error or anything, but when I launch the app, my Launch image only shows on iPad, not iPhone. This happens on the simulator AND device. I have done clean installs, cleaned out DerivedData, etc.

I also checked that my info.plist doesn't have anything to do with Launch images when I use asset catalogs, but nope, nothing in there.

Attaching screenshots to show how I have it set up with either method, any thoughts?

[image: one setup]

[image: the other way]

Comment: Have you tried on different simulators (The Retina 4 inch or Retina 4 inch 64-bit)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work in any simulators, 3.5 or 4 inch, and of course on the device.

Comment: I want to add 2 things I should have mentioned: The app is a Sprite Kit app in case that rings any bells for anyone, and also I tried this on both my Macs, same result on each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete your current LaunchImage and create a new one. Drag the
   images    to your project first and then substitute launch images
   for app    icons. Images.xcassets > Choose Editor > New Launch Image

   Check your LaunchImage preferences after you click on it -

   [image]
2. Goto Xcode > Product > Clean
3. Since, iPhone simulator is known to cache stuff, go ahead to iPhone
   Simulator > Reset Content and Settings (or manually delete the app from your iPhone simulator)
4. Don't forget to check your deployment settings (Target > General > Deployment Info). Universal app? Now, run your project in different iOS simulators and check for warnings!

Comment: Unfortunately, this yields no improvement or change.

Comment: Hah. Do you get 'any' warnings? @Cocorico

Comment: No, no warnings at all. And in fact, at one point I took out the 568h image and re-did it in Photoshop (to make sure I hadn't exported it as a jpeg by accident and just named it a png), and *then* I did get a warning, but I stuck it in, and Xcode was happy, 0 warnings, but it still comes up black. The fact it's black on iPhone but not iPad has to mean something, but I can't figure out what, my info.plist seems normal, there's nothing weird about the project, other than it's a Sprite Kit app which may have some bearing?