# ios app not fitting iphone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Firstly, I know this problem has asked before, but with other versions of XCode and those solutions don't work for me. Secondly, I am a .NET programmer and I am currently learning Swift so please be patient.

[ios app not fitting iphone 5 screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948432/ios-app-not-fitting-iphone-5-screen)

So I made an app with Swift, it is all done and it works perfectly(does what it should), but it doesn't look so great and I can't solve it.

This is how the app looks in simulator for 5S

[image]

But this is how it looks in real life:
[image]

I did made sure there is a Default-568h@2x.png image. I even deleted the launchimage

This is how the project looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I even set the size to 4 inch and no luck

[image]

Moreover, as I understood IOS should take care of fitting the app on different screen sizes with the above settings, but this is how it looks on 6 plus in the simulator:
[image]

Comment: Try simple stuff first like cleaning and rebuilding and deleting the app from the device. The iPhone 6 issue is probably your layout constraints (have you added any?)

Comment: Some of splash screens are missing, or the Default.png is missing.

Comment: I cleaned the project, deleted the app from the phone and redownloaded it, but still no luck. I didn't added a constrain on the layout on purpose, I might have added them unknowingly. Where do I check for them?

Comment: Reset contents and settings of iOS simulator and then run it

Comment: The problem is not the simulator. Even if I put the app on an Ipad, it still looks like that

Comment: Simulated metrics from IB are irrelevant, changing these values let you check how the view is supposed to be for different standard sizes, but you don't chose the final size there. The final size is governed by auto layout constraints, autoresizing masks or directly set frame depending on your implementation. An important thing to check is the size of the actual window of the application to see whether the window is downsized or it is just view: check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds.size`.

Comment: Have you set up autolayout constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, I don't know what I did different this time.
I followed these steps:
[iOS launch image won't show up on iPhone or simulator, works on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788688/ios-launch-image-wont-show-up-on-iphone-or-simulator-works-on-ipad)

and it worked even though I did tried them before....
Sorry for the repost and thanks to all who have answered!

My advice for anyone else who encounters this problem is to firstly be careful with the settings, the images(their resolution) and follow those steps